# Smooth LookRotation in Coroutine

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am rotating my camera to lookat a target object using Quaternion. I am using Quaternion.LookRotation and Quaternion.Slerp to make the camera rotate smoothly inside coroutine. Unfortunately the camera jitters a lot when rotating. How do I make the rotation smooth with my current code?

```
Quaternion targetRotation;
public Transform lookAtObject;

IEnumerator RotateTowardsTarget () {

        var duration = 2.0f;
        for (float t = 0.0f; t < duration; t += Time.deltaTime) {
            targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation (lookAtObject.position - transform.position);
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp (transform.rotation, targetRotation, t / duration);
            yield return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: why do this in `Update` though? simply get in inside the coroutine which is also proceeded every frame

Comment: It was in coroutine itself but it was the same problem with jitter. So i thought it would solve if i add to update(), but still it did not fix. I changed my code now.

Comment: So what exactly is supposed to happen? You want to look at the target for a certain amount of time ... or do you rather rotate towards that target within a given amount of time?

Comment: It should complete the rotation in given amount of time. As given the duration is 2 seconds, it should complete by then but do it smoothly, not jitter as it rotates.

Comment: I have tried Lerp as well and it has the same problem

Comment: ok and is the `lookAtObject` static for this full time or does it move?

Comment: Yes it is static. Only the camera rotates.

Answer (score 0):

You currently always start the lerp at the current rotation towards the target.

In your usecase what you rather want to do is store the initial rotation and rather interpolate between the initial and target rotation like

```
IEnumerator RotateTowardsTarget () 
{
    var duration = 2.0;

    // store the initial and target rotation once
    var startRotation = transform.rotation;
    var targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation (lookAtObject.position - transform.position);

    for (var timePassed = 0.0f; timePassed < duration; timePassed += Time.deltaTime) 
    {
        var factor = timePassed / duration;
        // optionally add ease-in and -out
        //factor = Mathf.SmoothStep(0, 1, factor);

        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp (startRotation, targetRotation, factor);
        yield return null;
    }

    // just to be sure to end up with clean values
    transform.rotation = targetRotation;
}
```

This will make the camera go from the current to the new rotation linear within 2 seconds

Comment: Hi, thank you for explanation. Shouldn't it be ```transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp (startRotation, targetRotation, (float) factor);```? Unfortunately now it does not rotate completely towards the target, it stops in midway, although it is smooth now.

Comment: @Programmer oh yeah sorry .. it should be `transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp (startRotation, targetRotation, factor);`

Comment: yes I did that but like I mentioned this time it does not even complete rotation. It stops midway.

Comment: are you sure that `Quaternion.LookRotation (lookAtObject.position - transform.position);` itself results in the correct rotation? I mean without the coroutine but just using `transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation (lookAtObject.position - transform.position);` ?

Comment: Yes ofc. I have tested my code like around 20 times so far :D It works properly. Tried in Update() before using in Coroutine.

Comment: but then I don't see reason why this shouldn't do it ... even if the loop was wrong it would still have to reach at the final line `transform.rotation = targetRotation;` and at least end up with the correct orientation in the end .... are you sure the routine itself runs to end and there is nothing else influencing the rotation?

Comment: Yes I have checked. It does not stop through anything else. I will check again.

Answer (score 0):

Slerp takes third parameter as progress not as actual time you can do this

```
       void Update () {
                
                    StartCoroutine(RotateOverTime(transform.rotation, 
                    lookAtObject.rotation, 1f / speed));
            }
         
            IEnumerator RotateOverTime (Quaternion originalRotation, Quaternion 
            finalRotation, float duration) {
                if (duration > 0f) {
                    float startTime = Time.time;
                    float endTime = startTime + duration;
                    transform.rotation = originalRotation;
                    yield return null;
                    while (Time.time < endTime) {
                        float progress = (Time.time - startTime) / duration;
                        // progress will equal 0 at startTime, 1 at endTime.
                        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp (originalRotation, 
                        finalRotation, progress);
                        yield return null;
                    }
                }
                transform.rotation = finalRotation;
            }
```

You can now send in duration as seconds